# Exponential map of 2x2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw the following formula (in (7.25) of [Lie Groups, Physics, and Geometry](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521884004))

$$
\exp\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    w & z\\
    0 & 1\\
  \end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    e^w & (e^w-1)z/w\\
    0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right).
$$

Is this correct or some kind of typo? At least for $z=0$, it does not seem right?

Comment: I get something like $\begin{pmatrix} e^{w} & \frac{(e^{w}-e)z}{w-1} \\ 0 & e \end{pmatrix}$. And Mathematica gives the same result as I got. I think there is a typo.

Comment: Yes, typo. See related [2216899#2216899](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876757/bch-baker-campbell-hausdorff-formula-for-x-y-xy-yx/2216899#2216899). This is the 1-dim affine group, 2-parameter and nonabelian. The Generators have a vanishing 2-2 entry, but the Group has a unit such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is indeed incorrect, including the case when $z=0$.

In the simple case that $z=0$, you have a diagonal matrix, and the exponential of a diagonal matrix $\exp\begin{pmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{pmatrix}$ is the diagonal of the exponentials $\begin{pmatrix}e^a&0\\0&e^b\end{pmatrix}$. In your case it would give 
$$\exp\begin{pmatrix}w&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}e^w&0\\0&e\end{pmatrix}.\tag1$$

In the general case that $z\neq0$, you need a general expression for the $n$th power of you matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}w&z\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, which is easy to see is of the form $M^n=\begin{pmatrix}w^n&u_n\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$, where $u_1=z$ and $u_{n+1}=wu_n+z$, so therefore $u_{n+1}=z\sum_{k=0}^nw^k=z\frac{w^{n+1}-1^{n+1}}{w-1}$.

Since the matrix exponential is defined as $\exp M=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!} M^n$, everything stays just as in (1) except the right-hand corner, which is given by
$$
\left(\exp M\right)_{12}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{u_n}{n!}
=\frac{z}{w-1}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{w^n}{n!}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1^n}{n!}\right]
=z\frac{e^w-e}{w-1}.
$$

The final result is then $$\boxed{\exp\begin{pmatrix}w&z\\0&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}e^w&z\frac{e^w-e}{w-1}\\0&e\end{pmatrix}.}\tag2$$

Answer (score 4):

The typo is in the last element of left-hand side matrix. The correct equation would be:
$$
\exp\left(
  \begin{array}{c}
    w & z\\
    0 & 0\\
  \end{array}
\right)
=
\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    e^w & (e^w-1)z/w\\
    0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Yes, this is another possibility, rather less violent on the original equation, and it makes more physical sense than having explicit $e=e^1$s in the equation.