# Why is there no $[X,[X,[X,Y]]]$ and $[Y,[Y,[X,Y]]]$ in the fourth order term of BCH formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

While trying to deal with [a problem involving BCH (Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff) formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876757/bch-baker-campbell-hausdorff-formula-for-x-y-xy-yx), I've noticed something strange. Everywhere in the literature I've managed to fetch (for example: [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2656) and [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1204.0389) paper, also [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_explicit_Baker.E2.80.93Campbell.E2.80.93Hausdorff_formula)), fourth order term is simply just:

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{24}[Y,[X,[X,Y]]]
\end{equation}

I understand that some commutators that might seem different are actually the same, for example $[X,[Y,[X,Y]]]$ and $[Y,[X,[X,Y]]]$, which can be simply shown:

\begin{equation}
[X,[Y,[X,Y]]]-[Y,[X,[X,Y]]]=
[\mathrm{ad}_X, \mathrm{ad}_Y][X,Y]=\mathrm{ad}_{[X,Y]}[X,Y]=0
\end{equation}

Therefore:

\begin{equation}
-\frac{1}{24}[Y,[X,[X,Y]]]=-\frac{1}{24}[X,[Y,[X,Y]]]
\end{equation}

But what about the terms with $[X,[X,[X,Y]]]$ and $[Y,[Y,[X,Y]]]$? Why are they not present? I fail to see how they cancel or can be written as a part the previously mentioned term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am only a physicist, and thus lack deep understanding of the combinatoric symmetry underlying [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number), namely the [recondite reason](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Why_do_the_odd_Bernoulli_numbers_vanish.3F) $B_{2n+1}=0$ for integers $n>0$. (*Note added* : actually the evenness of the shifted generating function [does it](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302594/bernoulli-odd-numbers-are-0-b-2n1-0-n0?rq=1).)

In your case, $B_3=0$ leads to the absence of $[X,[X,[X,Y]]]$ from the expansion, cf. W Miller's book (*Symmetry Groups and their Applications*, Academic Press, NY 1972, pp 159-161), or [my crib notes](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/CBH.pdf) for physics applications, Application Algorithm 1, the most popular.

Namely,
$$
\log (\exp X ~ \exp (tY)) |_{t=1}= X +\int_0^1 dt~ \psi ( e^{\operatorname{ad}X} e^{t\operatorname{ad}Y}) ~ Y ~,
$$
where $\psi (e^{-y})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n y^n/n!$ is the generating function of the Bernoulli numbers.

So, you see, in your case, for terms linear in *Y*, we are merely looking at 
$\psi(e^{\operatorname{ad}_X}) ~ Y$ and the cubic, quintic,... terms in *X* are missing. There should be a less "just-so" symmetry argument, to be sure.

The obverse argument for *X* - *Y* interchange follows by the antisymmetry of even powers of generators' terms.