# Prove following statements concerning Bernoulli polynomials

Tags: bernoulli-polynomials

> Let $B_n(x)$ be the Bernoulli Polynomial.
>
> 1) Show for $n\neq 1$ is $B_n(1)=B_n(0) (=B_n)$.
>
> 2) Determine $B_1=B_1(0)$ and $B_1(1)$.

I've already tried just to plug in the values in different kinds of Bernoulli Polynomial representations (with exception of integral representation, because we didn't have this definition at lecture) but i don't get the right solution. 
I would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Use the identity (see the [generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Representations)  of Bernoulli_polynomials):
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_n(x)}{n!}u^n = \frac{u e^{xu}}{e^u - 1}.$$
Then, by replacing $x$ with $1-x$ and $u$ with $-u$, we get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_n(1-x)}{n!}(-u)^n = \frac{-u e^{(1-x)(-u)}}{e^{-u} - 1}
=\frac{u e^{xu}}{e^{u}-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{B_n(x)}{n!}u^n.$$
which implies the symmetry $(-1)^nB_n(1-x)=B_n(x)$.

Moreover take a look at [Bernoulli odd numbers are 0 $B_{2n+1}=0,\;n>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302594/bernoulli-odd-numbers-are-0-b-2n1-0-n0)

Comment: @mojo Are you still interested in this problem?